# Parsley Validation not waiting for Remote Validation AsyncValidate to finish

Tags: jquery, validation, parsley.js, remote-validation, parsley

I have a form and I'm trying to do parsley remote validation on one of the fields, however, on form validation, the form submits before it waits for a response from the remote function (via asyncValidate()). Thus, even when the field is invalid, it'll show the field error css but the form still submits.

I tried using a $.Deferrede object but this isn't working.

```
function add_remote_validation() {

    var form = card.el.find('form');

    $(form).parsley().addAsyncValidator('validate_function', function (xhr) {

        return parseInt(xhr.responseText);
    });
}

add_remote_validation();

card.cards['my_card1'].on('validate', function(card){

    add_remote_validation();

    var result = $.Deferred();

    // test any asyncronous validation before doing regular validation
    $(form).parsley().asyncValidate()
        .done(function(){

            var valid = $(form).parsley().validate();

            if(valid) {

                result.resolveWith(valid);
            } else {

                result.rejectWith(valid);
            }
        })
        .fail(function(){

            result.rejectWith(false);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell if you need the `addAsynchValidator` at all (your code returns an integer, it should return `true` or `false`). If you do, you should call `window.Parsley.addAsyncValidator` (as you are told in a warning). The rest of the code should not be needed.

I'm assuming you are using the latest version.

Comment: You're right, I'm not using the latest version... I used a workaround in my controller (MVC structure) so that I'm not trying to do the validation through jQuery. Nonetheless, I'll mark this answer as correct.